# put canvas to the specific place on page

Tags: html, canvas, markup

How can i put canvas into the specific place on page? For example, I want to locate canvas inside the ascii "TV screen". How can i do that?

Thanks

```
                              o
                     o       /
                      \     /
                       \   /
                        \ /
    +--------------------v--------------------------+
    |  ______________________________________      @|
    | /                                     \       |
    | |                                     |  (\)  |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |       |
    | |                                     |  (-)  |
    | |                                     |       |
    | \                                     / :|||: |
    |  -ooo---------------------------------  :|||: |
    +-----------------------------------------------+
             []                    []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use compositing to restrict your drawing to the tv’s screen only**

Advantages:

- There's just the canvas element--no need to coordinate img+canvas with CSS.
- You can draw into a non-rectangular tv screen.
- You can use the tv screen like a "viewport".
- If resizing, keeping the viewport positioned properly is simpler.

It works like this:

Draw an image of a tv to your canvas:

```
ctx.drawImage(tv,0,0,tv.width,tv.height);
```

The important thing about this tv image is that **the screen has transparent pixels**

[image]

Before you draw anything to your screen, set the compositing to “destination-over”.  This causes canvas to preserve any non-transparent pixels that are already drawn on the screen (the tv) and to only draw into the transparent pixels (your tv screen).

Result: you’re ONLY drawing to the tv’s screen.    The rest of the tv is preserved.

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
```

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7JPrx/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: white; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var tv=new Image();
    var land=new Image();
    tv.onload=function(){
        land.onload=function(){
            draw();
        }
        land.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/landscape.png";
    }
    tv.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/tv1.png";

    var offsetX=0;

    function draw(){
        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        // draw the tv
        // NOTE: the screen of the tv must be transparent
        ctx.drawImage(tv,0,0,tv.width,tv.height);
        // begin drawing the screen
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        // this causes any drawing to ONLY draw over transparent pixels
        // that's how we draw within the screen because
        // the screen is the only part of the tv with transparent pixels
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
        // move (translate) our drawing to the screen part of the tv image
        ctx.translate(32,95);
        // draw the landscape scrolling across the screen (using offsetX)
        ctx.drawImage(land,offsetX,0);

        // reset
        ctx.restore();
        offsetX-=10;
        if(offsetX<=-600){offsetX=0;}
        setTimeout(draw,100);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use css commands to set the canvas position

```
position:relative; or position:absolute;
```

e.g

```
canvas{
         position:relative;
         top:Ypx;
         left:Xpx;
}
```